# Como usar e.preventDefault() apenas quando o formulario não for valido?

Tags: javascript, html, formulário, validação

Tenho uma página .html com um formulario de login, e um codigo .js para validar se os campos foram preenchidos corretamente. O problema é que não consigo validar os campos sem impedir que o formulario seja enviado e abra a proxima página devido ao e.preventDefault(), e quando impeço o envio para validar o formulario não consigo fazer com que ele abra a proxima página depois de validado.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Formulário</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Criar uma Conta</h2>
        </div>

        <form id="form" name="form" class="form" method="post" action="./page.html">
            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="username">Nome de Usuário</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Digite seu Nome de Usuário ..."/>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <small>Mensagem de Erro</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite seu Email ..."/>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <small>Mensagem de Erro</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="password">Senha</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Digite sua Senha ..."/>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <small>Mensagem de Erro</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <label for="password-confirmation">Confirmar Senha</label>
                <input type="password" id="password-confirmation" name="password-confirmation" placeholder="Confirme sua Senha ..."/>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <small>Mensagem de Erro</small>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7a4f7baffc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="./scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const passwordConfirmation = document.getElementById('password-confirmation');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    checkInputs();
    
});

function checkInputs() {
    const usernameValue = username.value;
    const emailValue = email.value;
    const passwordValue = password.value;
    const passwordConfirmationValue = passwordConfirmation.value;

    if (usernameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(username, 'O nome de usuário é obrigatório.');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(username);
    }

    if (emailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(email, 'O email é obrigatório.');
    } else if (!checkEmail(emailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(email, 'Insira um email válido.');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(email);
    }

    if (passwordValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(password, 'A senha é obrigatória.');
    } else if (passwordValue.length < 7) {
        setErrorFor(password, 'A senha deve conter no mínimo 7 caracteres.');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(password);
    }

    if (passwordConfirmationValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(passwordConfirmation, 'A confirmação de senha é obrigatoria.');
    } else if (passwordConfirmationValue !== passwordValue) {
        setErrorFor(passwordConfirmation, 'As senhas não conferem.');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(passwordConfirmation);
    }
    

    const formControls = form.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

    const formIsValid = [ ... formControls].every(formControl => {
        return (formControl.className === "form-control success");
    });

    if (formIsValid) {
        console.log('O formulário está 100% válido!');
    }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector("small");

    // Adicionar a mensagem de erro
    small.innerText = message;

    // Adicionar a classe de erro
    formControl.className = "form-control error";
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;

    // Adicionar a classe de sucesso
    formControl.className = "form-control success";
}

function checkEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(
      email
    );
}
```

Como posso fazer com que o e.preventDefault() só impeça a abertura da proxima página caso o formulario não esteja valido?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

você estava no caminho certo, apenas colocou um trecho do código na função errada.

Eu apenas tirei o final da tua função `checkInputs()` e coloquei na função `form.addEventListener()`.

E o código funcionou normalmente. Vou deixar abaixo como ficopu a função `form.addEventListener()`

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    
    checkInputs();

    const formControls = form.querySelectorAll('.form-control');

    const formIsValid = [ ... formControls].every(formControl => {
        return (formControl.className === "form-control success");
    });

    if (!formIsValid) {
        console.log('O formulário está inválido!');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```